# setting d3 graph from inside of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3

I am trying to read a JSON file which looks like:

```
[ {
"parent" : "cmeta_transform",
"path" : "hcat://sample/dt=yyyyMMddHH",
"child" : "lite_video_hourly"
} ]
```

Then, I am iterating over the contents and setting the Node and Edges from inside the `data.forEach` function call (code below)

But, it seems like the variable `g` is not getting set when I iterate over it. If I do it outside the anonymous function, it works.
What am I missing?

```
<script id="js">
// Create a new directed graph
var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});

d3.json("expectedOutput.json", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function (job) {
        console.log(job); // I do see job values correctly.
        g.setNode(job.child, { label: job.child });
        g.setEdge(job.parent,     job.child,     { label: job.path });
    });
});

console.log(g); // g doesn't have the nodes & edges values set above

// if I do this
g.setNode(job.child, { label: job.child });
g.setEdge(job.parent,     job.child,     { label: job.path });
console.log(g); // I see g is set properly
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because requesting the JSON via AJAX is an asynchronous operation so the `console.log` is executed before what's inside the anonymous function.

You may want to look at [promises in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks) or at least put your code inside that function so the result of the request is available to your code. At the simplest level this should work:

```
function draw(data) {
  var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});
  data.forEach(function (job) {
      console.log(job); // I do see job values correctly.
      g.setNode(job.child, { label: job.child });
      g.setEdge(job.parent,     job.child,     { label: job.path });
  });
  // carry on doing what you need in here...
}

d3.json("expectedOutput.json", draw);
```